# How do I get rid of the extra space on the Dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css

So I made a navigation bar with a drop down menu on hover but the problem is that the items in the list have acquired some extra `padding` on the left side out of no-where how can I remove the `padding`(I tried inspecting but couldn't find anything ).

HERE's the Problem :
[image: PROBLEM]

THIS IS WHAT I WANT :
[image: HOW IT SHOULD BE]

THE CODE:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500);
* {
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}


/*Header*/

header {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(../img/forheader.png);
    background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
    background: rgba(224, 228, 40, 0.7);
    padding: 2.5%;
}

.logo img {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 35%;
}


/*Header Over*/


/* NAVIGATION */

nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.unfixed {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
    transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px rgba(53, 53, 51, 0.12);
}

.fixed {
    background-color: hsla(152, 78%, 41%, 0.9);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
    transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px hsla(152, 78%, 41%, 0.54);
}

nav img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    display: none;
}

ul {
    position: absolute;
    right: 3%;
    line-height: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.unfixed ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'raleway';
    font-size: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.unfixed ul li a::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 15px;
    height: 1px;
    background: black;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s linear all;
    transition: 0.3s linear all;
}

.unfixed ul li a:hover::after {
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    left: 15px;
}

.fixed ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'raleway';
    font-size: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.fixed ul li a::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 15px;
    height: 1px;
    background: white;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s linear all;
    transition: 0.3s linear all;
}

.fixed ul li a:hover::after {
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    left: 15px;
}

/*DROP DOWN*/


nav ul li {
    position: relative;  
}

nav ul li ul {
     font-family: 'raleway';
     color: #fff; 
     font-size:24px;
     height: auto; 
     text-align:center;
     z-index:110;
     position: absolute; 
     left: 0; 
     right: 0; 
     top: 60px;
     -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
     -webkit-transform-origin-Y: 0;
     -webkit-transition:all .5s;
}
.unfixed ul li ul{ 
    width: 150px; 
    background: rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.87); 
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px  hsla(152, 1%, 67%, 0.54);
}
.fixed ul li ul{
    background-color: hsla(152, 78%, 41%, 0.9);
    width:150px;
    box-shadow:0px 5px 14px hsla(152, 78%, 41%, 0.54)
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
     -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    
}



/*NAVIGATION OVER*/
/*FOOTER*/

/*FOOTER*/

footer {
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(28, 29, 38, 0.95);
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
}

footer h3 {
    margin: 5px;
}

footer .social {
    font-size: 17px;
}

footer .social img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear all;
    transition: 0.4s linear all;
    -webkit-filter: saturate(0);
    -moz-filter: saturate(0);
    -o-filter: saturate(0);
    -ms-filter: saturate(0);
    filter: saturate(0);
}

footer .social img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: saturate(1);
    -moz-filter: saturate(1);
    -o-filter: saturate(1);
    -ms-filter: saturate(1);
    filter: saturate(1);
}

/*FOOTER OVER*/
/* SCROLL BAR AND SELECTION */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #444;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #E0E0E0;
    border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
}

::-moz-selection {
  color: white;
  background: #f01943;
}

::selection {
  color: white;
  background: #f01943;
}

@media screen and (max-width:850px) {
     .fixed ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'raleway';
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.unfixed ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'raleway';
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: 700;
}
nav img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    height: 0;
        display: none;
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Forum</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/nav.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/forum.css">
    <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/nav.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/forum.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <center><img src="../img/logo.png" alt="The Thrive Magazine"></center>
        </div>
    </header>
   
            <nav class="unfixed">
                <img src="../img/logo.png" alt="The Thrive Magazine">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="..//index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="column.html">Columns</a> 
            
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="column.html">Articles</a></li>
                     <center>  <li><a href="fashion.html">Fashion</a></li>
                    </center>    <li><a href="video.html">Videos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="interview.html">Interview</a></li>
                      </ul>
                      </li>
                    <li><a href="team.html">Team Thrive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sexed.html">Sex-Ed Module</a></li>     
                    <li><a href="forum.html">Share Your Story</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class = "arts">
            <div class="submission">
        <center>
            <h1>SHARE YOUR STORY</h1>
            <form action="submit.php" method="post">
                <label>Name :</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="optional">
                <br />
                <label>Title :</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="required" required="required">
                <br />
                <label>Your Story</label>
                <br />
                <textarea name="story" required="required"></textarea>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        </center>
        </div>
            <div class="row">
                    <article class="managerfc">
                        <h1 class="namerest">Submissions</h1>
                        <h2 class="desigrest">Manager - Fashion Column</h2>
                        <div class="inforest">
                            <p>Hi! I'm Jaya, I love fashion and believe that there is no easier way to express yourself than through your clothes.</p>
                            <br>
                            <p>Clothes aren't only an expression of who you are but are also a very good medium to share a message with people you meet. Fashion, through its passing conformities, helps to bridge the greater transitions of the process of social change.  Life isn't a dress rehearsal; it's the one and only life you've got.</p>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="creativedesig">
                        <h1 class="namerest">Social Feeds</h1>
                        
                        <div class="inforest">
                            <p>Hi I'm Anshul, I wish to spread love wherever I go. I do not believe in letting anyone come to me without leaving them a little bit happier. And that is why I have faith in Thrive- It has the power to spread love, happiness, hope... and magic.</p>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
                <h3>The Thrive Magazine. All Rights Reserved.</h3>
                <br>
                <h3>Site designed by Dhruv Agarwal, Rasik Raj and Kush Parmar.</h3>
                <h3>Introductory movie  by Jahanvi Chopra.</h3>
                <h3>Photographs by Jatin Kumar Sawhney.</h3>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="social">
                    We are social
                    <br>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/thethrivemag" target="_blank"><img src="../img/fb.png" alt="Social - Facebook"></a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/thethrive_mag?lang=en" target="_blank"><img src="../img/twitter.png" alt="Social - Twitter"></a>
                    <a href="https://instagram.com/thethrivemagazine/" target="_blank"><img src="../img/insta.png" alt="Social - Instagram"></a>
                    <br>
                    Reach us at:<br>
                    <u>thethrivemag@gmail.com</u>
                </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ul`has `padding` by default so just reset it by adding `padding:0` to your `nav ul li ul`

**Notes**

`<center>`  is deprecated so **don't** use it

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500);
 * {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}
/*Header*/

header {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(../img/forheader.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
.logo {
  background: rgba(224, 228, 40, 0.7);
  padding: 2.5%;
}
.logo img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 35%;
}
/*Header Over*/

/* NAVIGATION */

nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.unfixed {
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
  transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px rgba(53, 53, 51, 0.12);
}
.fixed {
  background-color: hsla(152, 78%, 41%, 0.9);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
  transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px hsla(152, 78%, 41%, 0.54);
}
nav img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3%;
  line-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.unfixed ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'raleway';
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.unfixed ul li a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 15px;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s linear all;
  transition: 0.3s linear all;
}
.unfixed ul li a:hover::after {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  left: 15px;
}
.fixed ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'raleway';
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.fixed ul li a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 15px;
  height: 1px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s linear all;
  transition: 0.3s linear all;
}
.fixed ul li a:hover::after {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  left: 15px;
}
/*DROP DOWN*/

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li ul {
  font-family: 'raleway';
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 110;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 60px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin-Y: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  padding: 0
}
.unfixed ul li ul {
  width: 150px;
  background: rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.87);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px hsla(152, 1%, 67%, 0.54);
}
.fixed ul li ul {
  background-color: hsla(152, 78%, 41%, 0.9);
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px hsla(152, 78%, 41%, 0.54)
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
}
/*NAVIGATION OVER*/

/*FOOTER*/

/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(28, 29, 38, 0.95);
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}
footer h3 {
  margin: 5px;
}
footer .social {
  font-size: 17px;
}
footer .social img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear all;
  transition: 0.4s linear all;
  -webkit-filter: saturate(0);
  -moz-filter: saturate(0);
  -o-filter: saturate(0);
  -ms-filter: saturate(0);
  filter: saturate(0);
}
footer .social img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: saturate(1);
  -moz-filter: saturate(1);
  -o-filter: saturate(1);
  -ms-filter: saturate(1);
  filter: saturate(1);
}
/*FOOTER OVER*/

/* SCROLL BAR AND SELECTION */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #444;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #E0E0E0;
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
}
::-moz-selection {
  color: white;
  background: #f01943;
}
::selection {
  color: white;
  background: #f01943;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  .fixed ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'raleway';
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .unfixed ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'raleway';
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  nav img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <center>
      <img src="../img/logo.png" alt="The Thrive Magazine">
    </center>
  </div>
</header>

<nav class="unfixed">
  <img src="../img/logo.png" alt="The Thrive Magazine">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="..//index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="column.html">Columns</a> 

      <ul>
        <li><a href="column.html">Articles</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="fashion.html">Fashion</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="video.html">Videos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="interview.html">Interview</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="team.html">Team Thrive</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="sexed.html">Sex-Ed Module</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="forum.html">Share Your Story</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="arts">
  <div class="submission">
    <h1>SHARE YOUR STORY</h1>
    <form action="submit.php" method="post">
      <label>Name :</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="optional">
      <br />
      <label>Title :</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="required" required="required">
      <br />
      <label>Your Story</label>
      <br />
      <textarea name="story" required="required"></textarea>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <article class="managerfc">
      <h1 class="namerest">Submissions</h1>
      <h2 class="desigrest">Manager - Fashion Column</h2>
      <div class="inforest">
        <p>Hi! I'm Jaya, I love fashion and believe that there is no easier way to express yourself than through your clothes.</p>
        <br>
        <p>Clothes aren't only an expression of who you are but are also a very good medium to share a message with people you meet. Fashion, through its passing conformities, helps to bridge the greater transitions of the process of social change. Life
          isn't a dress rehearsal; it's the one and only life you've got.</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="creativedesig">
      <h1 class="namerest">Social Feeds</h1>
      <div class="inforest">
        <p>Hi I'm Anshul, I wish to spread love wherever I go. I do not believe in letting anyone come to me without leaving them a little bit happier. And that is why I have faith in Thrive- It has the power to spread love, happiness, hope... and magic.</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <h3>The Thrive Magazine. All Rights Reserved.</h3>
  <br>
  <h3>Site designed by Dhruv Agarwal, Rasik Raj and Kush Parmar.</h3>
  <h3>Introductory movie  by Jahanvi Chopra.</h3>
  <h3>Photographs by Jatin Kumar Sawhney.</h3>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="social">
    We are social
    <br>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/thethrivemag" target="_blank">
      <img src="../img/fb.png" alt="Social - Facebook">
    </a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/thethrive_mag?lang=en" target="_blank">
      <img src="../img/twitter.png" alt="Social - Twitter">
    </a>
    <a href="https://instagram.com/thethrivemagazine/" target="_blank">
      <img src="../img/insta.png" alt="Social - Instagram">
    </a>
    <br>Reach us at:
    <br>
    <u>thethrivemag@gmail.com</u>
  </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.unfixed ul {padding-left:0;}` to your style sheet to remove the default padding of 40px from the left of dropdown menus.